# Firebase Firestore endBefore() handling for at the end of data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to code a pagination for my app and i meet a problem with endBefore().

Here is my code:

```
  chatsRef
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  .endBefore(latestMessage)
  .limit(5)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) =>
        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
          console.log(
            {
              ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            }
          );
          latestMessage = {
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          };
          
        })
      );
```

As you can see i set the `latestMessage` in each function call but the problem is that when the pagination reach the oldest message and set `latestMessage` with it. The query still get the oldest message again and again. Is there any way for getting null object or not returning any value.

Actually I just want to get to object that is older than `latestMessage`(`latestMessage` is not included) but i dont do that anyway.

SIMPLE OUTPUT:

if `latestMessage` is: (There is one message that is older than that)

```
Object {
  "_id": "73dd0b64-5fca-452a-9256-4b0bf6879031",
  "createdAt": t {
    "nanoseconds": 161000000,
    "seconds": 1613245061,
  },
  "text": "Dkdodndpdn",
}
```

But the output return 5 message and 3 of them is newer than `latestMessage` 1 of them is `latestMessage` and one of them is the older message

```
    Object { -->The oldest message
      "_id": "2f1a0537-cfe7-45ac-b284-757dadab48e8",
      "createdAt": t {
        "nanoseconds": 191000000,
        "seconds": 1613230217,
      },
      "text": "rr",
    }

Object { --> Same message with latestMessage
  "_id": "73dd0b64-5fca-452a-9256-4b0bf6879031",
  "createdAt": t {
    "nanoseconds": 161000000,
    "seconds": 1613245061,
  },
  "text": "Dkdodndpdn",
}

Object { -->These 3 messages is newer and i dont want it but it returned by firestore
  "_id": "190f3370-e320-4bc7-bb38-b3e80de60939",
  "createdAt": t {
    "nanoseconds": 601000000,
    "seconds": 1613301778,
  },
  "text": "Se",

}
Object {
  "_id": "fea40c2b-0d94-4445-a5b5-ed9535fd5e52",
  "createdAt": t {
    "nanoseconds": 248000000,
    "seconds": 1613301833,
  },
  "text": "456",
}
Object {
  "_id": "289d2055-e278-4e43-96c1-6a16ccff2d96",
  "createdAt": t {
    "nanoseconds": 972000000,
    "seconds": 1613301912,
  },
  "text": "Sa4",

}
```

Comment: I also think this is not right, it must be a bug. It doesn't work as the name would suggest and also it's illogical.

Comment: Got the same error now

Answer (score 0):

What you see with `endBefore(latestMessage)` is the expected result because you are getting the new result by starting with the one before the latest message.

A better way to implement pagination is to use startAfter as in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query)

```
var first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

return first.get().then((documentSnapshots) => {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(25);
});
```